# Combine didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following problem: The segue should only be performed if the UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone is true.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Update" sender:indexPath];{

        }
    }
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{          
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Update"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selected = [self.travelA objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        TravelVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.travel = selected;
        destViewController.positionString =  _positionStringA;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The segue will also be performed if the cell selection style is not UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone. Maybe there's a way to combine both methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be basing your logic on the cell setting of `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`. Instead, you should be using the `indexPath` to interrogate your model and find out if selection is available / sensible for that item.